# Horizontal Alignment - HTML

Tags: html

I want to align the header information. However, I could not able to figure out how to make FnName, B and BitTy object align horizontally rather than putting space in between.

```
headerList = '<h3><li contenteditable="true">'+'<text>'+ aut.FnName +'</text>'+"       |        "+'<text>'+this.B+'</text>'+"       |        "+'<text>'+this.BitTy+'</text>'+'</li></h3>';
wNameList = '<div><ul>';
```

Comment: what is your expected output that you want to achieve... your question is very unclear

Comment: Are you sure you mean vertical alignment?

Comment: There are three objects listed on the header. I want them to be aligned vertically.

Comment: That's horizontal alignment. Also, what's `<text>`? There is no `<text>` element.

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean horizontal alignment

Comment: I put <text> on purpose to allow editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by giving a fixed width to the `text` elements.

```
#accordion li > text{display:inline-block;}
#accordion li > text:nth-child(1){width:150px;}
#accordion li > text:nth-child(2){width:100px;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/3/
***notice***: if the text exceeds the available space it will wrap.

---

*keep in mind that you code produces very invalid html and that means more problems..*

Comment: Hello Gaby, thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate invalid html in detail, then I will refine my code based on your feedback

Comment: @casillas you create `li` elements directly under `h3`. That is invalid. They can only be children of `ul` elements.

Comment: I see your point, I am going to fix it. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can set these `<text>` elements you've created  to align with:

```
text {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xg7cr0g4/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Fix size of text elements :

HTML :

```
headerList = '<h3><li contenteditable="true">'+
  '<text class="formationName">'+ aut.FormationName + '</text>'+
  ' | ' +
  '<text class="bitSize">'+this.BitSize + '</text>'+
  ' | ' +
  '<text class="bitType">'+this.BitType + '</text>'+
  '</li></h3>';
```

CSS :

```
#accordion li > text{
    display:inline-block; 
    text-align : center;

}
#accordion .formationName {
    width:120px; 
    text-align : center;
}

#accordion .bitSize {
    width:100px; 
    text-align : center;
}

#accordion .bitType {
    width:100px; 
    text-align : center;
}
```

See this url : http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/8/

Comment: Thanks a lot Karim. It is very well written.